# Best way to have absolute imports with Webpack 2?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm in the process of setting up a Webpack configuration for a React project and I want to be able to import my components like this:

```
import ComponentName from "components/ComponentName"
```

instead of like this:

```
import ComponentName from "../../components/ComponentName"
```

(this all would be assuming that my `components` directory lives inside a `src` directory)

Doing a little bit of research, so far I've found two different methods to achieve this using Webpack:

1. Making Webpack resolve modules inside my `src` directory using the `resolve.modules` option like this:

   ```
       resolve: {
         modules: [ path.resolve(__dirname, "src"), path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")]
       }
   ```
2. Using the Alias option to name my components directory as an alias:

   ```
       resolve: {
         alias: {
           components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/'),
          }
       }
   ```

So, my question is, is there any advantage of using one particular method over the other ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use alias you can import your code like this

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    AliasName: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/'),
   }
}

import Comp from 'AliasName/Comp'
```

Where as when you dont use alias your code would look like this

```
resolve: {
  modules: [ path.resolve(__dirname, "src"), path.resolve(__dirname, 
  "node_modules")]
}

import Comp from 'components/Comp'
```

I would go with the alias cause it looks a lot cleaner but there is no real advantage to it. Just the look and feel