# How to import SASS file in React Webpack relative to project's root directory

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass

I want to be able to import a SASS file in a React component relative to the project's root directory, as opposed to having to do it relative to the component.

I want to be able to do the following in the componenet:

```
import styles from "styles/popup.sass"
```

as opposed to

```
import styles from "../../styles/popup.sass"
```

I used the resolve options in order to be able to do this and it works for other file types (i.e. .js and .png), but it does not work for .sass files. I get the following error:

```
Cannot find module 'styles/popup.sass'
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working for SASS files and would really appreciate any help.

**Project Structure**:

```
src
- js
  - popup
    - greeting_componenet.jsx
- styles
  - popus.sass
```

**Webpack Config file**

```
var webpack = require("webpack"),
    path = require("path"),
    fileSystem = require("fs"),
    env = require("./utils/env"),
    CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin").CleanWebpackPlugin,
    CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin"),
    HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin"),
    WriteFilePlugin = require("write-file-webpack-plugin");

// load the secrets
var alias = {};

var secretsPath = path.join(__dirname, ("secrets." + env.NODE_ENV + ".js"));

var fileExtensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "eot", "otf", "svg", "ttf", "woff", "woff2"];

if (fileSystem.existsSync(secretsPath)) {
  alias["secrets"] = secretsPath;
}

var options = {
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || "development",
  entry: {
    popup: path.join(__dirname, "src", "js", "popup.js"),
    options: path.join(__dirname, "src", "js", "options.js"),
    background: path.join(__dirname, "src", "js", "background.js")
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "[name].bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader",
        include: [
          path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
          /node_modules\/(semantic-ui-css)/
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|sass)$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: {
                localIdentName: "[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
              }, 
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: function() {
                return [require('autoprefixer')]
              }
            }
          },

          'sass-loader'
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: new RegExp('\.(' + fileExtensions.join('|') + ')$'),
        loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]",
        include: [
          path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
          /node_modules\/(semantic-ui-css)/
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "html-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: alias,
    extensions: fileExtensions.map(extension => ("." + extension)).concat([".jsx", ".js", ".css", ".sass"]),
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      'node_modules'
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // clean the build folder
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    // expose and write the allowed env vars on the compiled bundle
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(["NODE_ENV"]),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: "src/manifest.json",
      transform: function (content, path) {
        // generates the manifest file using the package.json informations
        return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({
          description: process.env.npm_package_description,
          version: process.env.npm_package_version,
          ...JSON.parse(content.toString())
        }))
      }
    }]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, "src", "popup.html"),
      filename: "popup.html",
      chunks: ["popup"]
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, "src", "options.html"),
      filename: "options.html",
      chunks: ["options"]
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, "src", "background.html"),
      filename: "background.html",
      chunks: ["background"]
    }),
    new WriteFilePlugin()
  ]
};

if (env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  options.devtool = "cheap-module-eval-source-map";
}

module.exports = options;
```

Comment: Does your setup only affect sass files and other files allow absolute imports? If not and you need it for all file imports, then you might have to setup `absolute paths` (base paths/ aliases) with your webpack. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384356/best-way-to-have-absolute-imports-with-webpack-2) , or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384356/best-way-to-have-absolute-imports-with-webpack-2).

Comment: Hi @iamcastelli I implemented what the links suggested and unfortunately it still doesn't work. It seems to just affect styling files for some odd reason (i.e. .sass and .css). I can import a .js file from the `styles` folder. Maybe its the way I've configured my style loaders. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add aliases for styles.

Something like:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      styles: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/styles/'),
      js: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/') 
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this and I get the same issue. But I am able to import a .js file like this: `import "styles/test.js"`, but it does not work for the .sass file. It seems to be just affecting the .sass files. Any thoughts on this?